# How can I change the default icon in "clear" option of textAngular directive toolbar?

Tags: angularjs

The textAngular directive (https://github.com/fraywing/textAngular) has many presets like add links, blockquotes, etc, but I want to change default icon in clear formatting option on toolbar. How can I do that?

Comment: https://github.com/fraywing/textAngular/blob/master/demo/static-demo.html

Comment: Ties, when I change I receive this error "Uncaught textAngular Error: A unique name is required for a Tool Definition"

Comment: I just want to edit the default clear option, not add a new one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work according to https://github.com/fraywing/textAngular/blob/master/demo/static-demo.html:

```
angular.module("changeIconTest", ['textAngular'])
    .config(function($provide){
        $provide.decorator('taTools', ['$delegate', function(taTools){

            taTools.clear.iconclass = 'icon-ban-circle'; // Use any font-awesome identifier
            return taTools;

        }]);
    });
```

Comment: An more: using the attribute "buttontext" I put some more text with the icon. :)

Comment: @ThiagoVerney no problem. Please vote up and accept as answer :)